# How to set generate new ID for data added from POST API method

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a model like below:

```cs
public class Product
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string productID { get; set; } = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();

    public string productName { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string image_product { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

My post method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("add")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public ActionResult<Product> AddProduct(Product product)
{
    //If Product already Exist
    var check = _setting.GetDetailProduct(product.productName, product.branch);
    if (check != null)
    {
        return Ok("Product existed");
    }

    // Add product
    _setting.Create(product);

    return CreatedAtRoute("AddProduct", new { id = product.productID.ToString() }, product);
}
```

When I add try product,Json add will convert into product model data but the ID not auto generated and only get from input json data.

So I wonder is there any method that I can add method for parameter data?

I have try to create a new model variable (this surely will have new generated ID) and put data from parameter data. but with this solution really bad when my model structure have updated more field.

Comment: What database are you inserting into? Mongo?

Comment: yes it is Mongo, also the method GenerateNewId that i use above is from MongoDB.Bson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/insert/#std-label-csharp-insert-guide).

> In a MongoDB collection, each document must contain an _id field with
> a unique field value.
>
> MongoDB allows you to manage this field in two ways:
>
> You can set this field for each document yourself, ensuring each _id
> field value is unique.
>
> You can let the driver automatically generate unique ObjectId values
> for each document _id. If you do not manually set an _id field value
> for a document, the driver will populate the field with an ObjectId.
>
> Unless you can guarantee uniqueness, MongoDB recommends you let the
> driver automatically generate _id values.

Why not Let the package handle generation of the new id?

All you have to do is change your `productiD` property to

```cs
 [BsonId]
 public ObjectId productID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it really work and maybe i think kinda complex and wrong way (that it only auto generate when adding in mongodb ).